# How to find Multiple NSRange for a string from full string iOS swift

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsrange

```
let fullString = "Hello world, there are \(string(07)) continents and \(string(195)) countries."
let range = [NSMakeRange(24,2), NSMakeRange(40,3)]
```

Need to find the NSRange for numbers in the entire full string and there is a possibility that both numbers can be same. Currently hard coding like shown above, the message can be dynamic where hard coding values will be problematic.

I have split the strings and try to fetch `NSRange` since there is a possibility of same value. like stringOne and stringTwo.

```
func findNSMakeRange(initialString:String, fromString: String) {
        let fullStringRange = fromString.startIndex..<fromString.endIndex
        fromString.enumerateSubstrings(in: fullStringRange, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
            let start = distance(fromString.startIndex, substringRange.startIndex)
            let length = distance(substringRange.startIndex, substringRange.endIndex)
            let range = NSMakeRange(start, length)

            if (substring == initialString) {
                print(substring, range)
            }
        })
    }
```

Receiving errors like `Cannot invoke distance with an argument list of type (String.Index, String.Index)`

Anyone have any better solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say that you want to iterate through `NSRange` matches in a string so that you can apply a bold attribute to the relevant substrings.

In Swift 5.7 and later, you can use the new [`Regex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex):

```swift
string.ranges(of: /\d+/)
    .map { NSRange($0, in: string) }
    .forEach {
        attributedString.setAttributes(attributes, range: $0)
    }
```

Or if you find the traditional regular expressions too cryptic, you can import [`RegexBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder), and you can use the new regex DSL:

```swift
string.ranges(of: Regex { OneOrMore(.digit) })
    .map { NSRange($0, in: string) }
    .forEach {
        attributedString.setAttributes(attributes, range: $0)
    }
```

---

Now, this pattern of mapping the `Range<String.Index>` to a `NSRange` is only necessary if you really need an `NSRange`, which is rarely needed nowadays. E.g., if you just wanted to print the subranges, you might just do:

```swift
string.ranges(of: /\d+/)
    .forEach { print(string[$0]) }
```

Or, if you needed to update a mutable `AttributedString` on the basis of finding ranges within the original `String`, you might map to a `Range<AttributedString.Index>`:

```swift
string.ranges(of: /\d+/)
    .compactMap { Range($0, in: attributedString) }
    .forEach { attributedString[$0].foregroundColor = .blue }
```

But the key takeaway is that we can now use native `Regex` literals surrounded by `/` characters, like shown above.

---

In Swift versions prior to 5.7, one would use [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/). E.g.:

```swift
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)
try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+").enumerateMatches(in: string, range: range) { result, _, _ in
    guard let range = result?.range else { return }
    attributedString.setAttributes(attributes, range: range)
}
```

Because the regex backslash was inside a string, that has to be escaped by yet another backslash (which is why this has two backslashes in it). Or you can use extended string delimiters, replacing `"\\d+"` with `#"\d+"#`.

---

Personally, before Swift 5.7, I found it useful to have a method to return an array of Swift ranges, i.e. `[Range<String.Index>]`:

```swift
extension StringProtocol {
    func ranges<T: StringProtocol>(of string: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        var start: Index = startIndex
        
        while let range = range(of: string, options: options, range: start ..< endIndex) {
            ranges.append(range)
            
            if !range.isEmpty {
                start = range.upperBound               // if not empty, resume search at upper bound
            } else if range.lowerBound < endIndex {
                start = index(after: range.lowerBound) // if empty and not at end, resume search at next character
            } else {
                break                                  // if empty and at end, then quit
            }
        }
        
        return ranges
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
let string = "Hello world, there are 09 continents and 195 countries."
let ranges = string.ranges(of: "[0-9]+", options: .regularExpression)
```

And then you can `map` the `Range` to `NSRange`. Going back to the original example, if you wanted to make these numbers bold in some attributed string:

```swift
string.ranges(of: "[0-9]+", options: .regularExpression)
    .map { NSRange($0, in: string) }
    .forEach { attributedString.setAttributes(boldAttributes, range: $0) }
```

---

Resources:

- Swift 5.7 and later:

  - WWDC 2022 video [Meet Swift Regex](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110357/)
  - WWDC 2022 video [Swift Regex: Beyond the basics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110358/)
  - Hacking With Swift: [Regular Expressions](https://Regular%20expressions%20Available%20from%20Swift%205.7)
- Swift before 5.7:

  - Hacking With Swift: [How to use regular expressions in Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/108/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-swift)
  - NSHipster: [Regular Expressions in Swift](https://nshipster.com/swift-regular-expressions/)

Comment: I am passing `NSRange` to set bold attribute to the `Numbers` in string.

Comment: Yeah I did implemented the bold attributed part, problem was only hardcoding ranges. Your answer fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This works but doesn't take into account multiple recurring strings combined in the same string. For example: Searching for `aa` in `aaa aaa` should bold all the text. Instead the above only bolds the first occurrences. This is due to starting from the upper bound of the previous range.

Comment: Note: Updating the code with this: `start = index(after: range.lowerBound)` captures all recurring strings even if they are contained in others. Making it slightly more accurate.

Comment: @simon_smiley - I wouldn’t your approach as as “more accurate”. For example, Apple’s own [`enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409687-enumeratematches) behaves like my answer above (where searching for “aa” in “aaaa” will return two results, not three). You might prefer the behavior you describe, and if it solves your particular problem, then that’s fine, do that. But I think your behavior is non-standard, not “more accurate”.

Comment: @simon_smiley - FWIW, if you want to search for occurrences of sequences of 2 or more `a` characters, you really should just use the aforementioned regex enumeration method but with `let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "a{2,}")`.

Comment: I suppose it comes down to definition. I agree that my answer solves my particular problem. Neither solution can be considered always correct. Both answers provide a specific subset. In retrospect I should have left off my final sentence to make my comment more useful.

Comment: @Rob `where Index == String.Index` that constrain is not needed anymore. Btw `while let range = range(of: string, options: options, range: start..<endIndex)` can also be written as `while let range = self[start...].range(of: string, options: options) {`.  FYI IFAIR that might result in a infinite loop if your regex returns empty string ranges.

Comment: Thanks. Modified to remove unnecessary constraint and now handling edge-case that might result in zero length matches.

Comment: Was scratching my head for a while over this 'before Swift 5.7' solution, until I noticed [`setAttributes(_:range:)`](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=setAttributes(_:range:)&type=Documentation) is only defined on `NSMutableAttributedString`, not `NSAttributedString` or `AttributedString`.

Comment: No, the `NSRange` and attributed string stuff has absolutely nothing to do with the “before Swift 5.7” comment. The key observation is that native regex support with the `/`, e.g. `string.ranges(of: /foo/)`, was only introduced to the language in Swift 5.7. Before that we had to use `range(of:options:range:)` with the `.regularExpression` option, or, worse, `NSRegularExpression`. My use of `NSMutableAttributedString`’s `setAttributes` is not really relevant to the question at hand, only present because the OP was building an array of `NSRange`…